# Multiple imputation with intermediate variables

Tags: causality, multiple-imputation, missing-data

Can intermediate variables be used in multiple imputation to predict missingness in covariates?

Example: Suppose treatment X impacts Z which impacts  Y. Now suppose you have control variables (C)  where some of the variables have missing values. Can Z be included in your model to predict missing values of C?